# Slowing down blinking rate on an LED with built in IC

Tags: led

I have a Kingbright, L-796BSRC-B SUPER BRIGHT RED blinking LED with built in IC. Having just installed a new home wireless alarm system which has a battery powered external sounder, I wanted to connect the existing 12v supply of the old, redundant wired in box to this LED to run as a permanent indicator. I did and it's working fine but blinking rather too quickly. Can I simply slow down the blinking rate from obviously outside the IC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling "Kingbright L-796BSRC-B datasheet" finds the [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/67108.pdf) for this device.  On page 2 it shows that \$f\$ is 1.5 to 3Hz for a voltage of 3.5v to 14v, and the graph on page 3 shows that the rate *decreases* with voltage. So *increase* the applied voltage, and the rate will slow.

But you won't get much change by moving from 12V to 14V, so it's time to pick a different LED.